# Filter list by value

Tags: python, regex, list, filter

I have a list like this

```
ls = ['5 k', 'k', '13 k', 'k']
```

I want to get a list with value including digits

```
ls = ['5 k', '13 k']
```

I did this as below

```
import re
y = [x for x in ls if x == re.compile('^\d+$')]
y
```

and get

```
[]
```

The same is for this version

```
r = re.compile('^[0-9]+$')
for e in filter(r.match, ls):
    print(e)
```

How to fix it?

Comment: `re.search()`??

Comment: `^\d+$` means *digits and only digits from start to end*.

Comment: `[x for x in ls if re.findall('\d [a-zA-Z]', x)]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `re.search`, also you don't need the anchors if you just want to test if the string contains a digit. `^[0-9]+$` will match strings that contain digits only:

```
import re
ls = ['5 k', 'k', '13 k', 'k']
​
[x for x in ls if re.search(r'\d', x)]
# ['5 k', '13 k']
```

If you want to test if the string starts with a digit, use `re.match`:

```
[x for x in ls if re.match(r'\d', x)]
​
# ['5 k', '13 k']
```

---

Both of these two functions return an object (trusy) if match is found, and None (falsy) otherwise, so they can be used with `if` as boolean condition to filter elements.

Answer (score 1):

You can filter this list with Python alone:

```
>>> ls = ['5 k', 'k', '13 k', 'k']
>>> [s for s in ls if any(c.isdigit() for c in s)]
['5 k', '13 k']
```

`any` will 'short-circuit' on the first True, so it is pretty efficient.

Nothing wrong with a regex to be sure, but this may be faster if you have a larger data set.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> [el for el in ls if filter(str.isdigit, el)]
['5 k', '13 k']
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing matching `k` in the regex. Try `'^\d+ k$'`.

Answer (score 0):

Your regex doesn't match what you want but only a string that is a sequence of digits.

You'd better try with `'^\d+ k$'`.

```
import re
y = [x for x in ls if x == re.compile('^\d+ k$')]
y
```

Answer (score 0):

There are other answers for regex solutions, but it's worth pointing out that you don't necessarily need to use regex to filter these. For example, based on the current content, you could filter out anything that's missing a space (The regex solutions I see so far are all requiring the space to be there anyway).

```
[x for x in ls if ' ' in x]
```